# I am having problems with pointers in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have function which takes string pointer's pointer `foo(char **str)`

when I write:

```
//this code makes error-Segmentation fault (core dumped)
char x[2];
x[0] = 'a';
x[1] = '\0';
foo(&x);
```

but when I write

```
char x[2];
x[0] = 'a';
x[1] = '\0';
char *a = x;
foo(&a); //code works perfectly
```

Can anyone explain what the difference between these two code snippets is?

Comment: ...and what's foo?

Comment: What does `foo()` do?

Comment: The first fragment is not valid C++, and [does not compile](http://rextester.com/JQUYD73122). `&x` has a type of `char (*)[2]`, not `char**`. You must be compiling as C, which allows silent casts between pointers of arbitrary unrelated types.

Comment: can u explain what is not valid?

Comment: Which part of "`char (*)[2]` is not `char**`" do you find unclear?

Comment: code is written in C

Comment: x is char * and &x will be char **

Comment: Well, like I said, C provides very little in the way of type safety, and in particular, allows one to silently convert between pointers of arbitrary types. That doesn't mean that any such conversion is in fact meaningful - it's up to the programmer to know what they are doing. Here, a conversion from `&x` to `char**` is not, in fact, meaningful, and the program trying to use the resulting pointer exhibits undefined behavior. By contrast, C++ enforces pretty strict type safety, and thus disallows such invalid conversion at compile time.

Comment: No, `x` is `char[2]` and `&x` is `char (*)[2]`

Answer (score 4):

In this function call

```
foo(&x);
```

the argument has type `char ( * )[2]` that is it is a pointer to an array of two elements.

In this function call

```
foo(&a);
```

the argument has type `char **` that is it is a pointer to pointer.

Thus the correct call depends on how the corresponding function parameter is declared.:)

As the function parameter has type `char **` then the second call is correct. There is no implicit conversion from type `char ( * )[2]` to type `char **`, so the compiler will issue an error for the first function call.

The difference between these two types is that dereferencing  operator * applied to the first pointer yields array of type `char[2]` while dereferencing operator applied to the second pointer yelds again pointer of type `char *`.

The confusion for beginners is that for both pointers you can apply the  subscript operator twice like `ptr[i][j]` where `ptr` is a pointer of either type and as result they look similarly.